Saving an emf image as png using apache.poi results in some parts of the image turning black
I am working on a vsdx parser for the vector editor we are doing at work. Alongside vsdx, it can import images, such as wmf/emf. Our editor can't display emf files natively, so we convert them to png using apache poi lib (code example below). The issue is that it converts some parts of the image in pure black.
If it helps, the image itself is located in one of the Visio stencils (Software and Database -> Web Diagram -> Web Site Map Shapes, Graphic (bitmap) element).
initial emf and resulting png
Code that is used to convert emf to png:
        File f = new File(".\\workspace\\image1.emf");
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f))
        {
            HemfPicture emf = new HemfPicture(fis);
            Dimension2D dim = emf.getSize();
            int width = Units.pointsToPixel(dim.getWidth());
            int height = Units.pointsToPixel(dim.getHeight());
            double max = Math.max(width, height);

            if (max > 1500) {
                width *= (int) (1500 / max);
                height *= (int) (1500 / max);
            }

            BufferedImage bufImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics2D g = bufImg.createGraphics();
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
            g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            emf.draw(g, new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,width,height));
            g.dispose();

            ImageIO.write(bufImg, "PNG", new File(".\\workspace\\image1.png"));
        }


Is there any quick fix that I could apply, without changing a lib?
I tried changing some of the rendering hints and image type when creating BufferedImage, but it didnt' help.
